# Como apresentar resultados do Google Analytics no website?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Já há algum tempo que uso o Google Analytics, mas agora queria mostrar os resultados numa página. Estou com alguns problemas a perceber o seu funcionamento. Gostaria que me aconselhassem um guia/tutorial ou que me explicassem como usar.

Answer (score 2):

Há [um tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) sobre como usar a API do Analytics, disponível para Java, Python, PHP e JavaScript.

Também existem bibliotecas que simplificam o uso da API dele: a [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) da própria Google (há um [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089698/1850091) dela nessa resposta do SO), a [gapi-google-analytics-php-interface](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) e a [Google-Analytics-API-PHP](https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP), [entre outras](https://github.com/search?q=google+analytics+api+php).

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é criar um widget que mostre as estatísticas que pretende só inserindo algum HTML e JavaScript que faz requisições AJAX para pegar os dados a mostrar.

Porém é mais seguro que esse widget acesse um script de PHP no seu servidor, do que acessar a API do Google Analytics diretamente, pois você não quer que terceiros acessem quaisquer estatísticas do seu site.

Existem vários componentes prontos em PHP para fazer exatamente isso, como por exemplo o [SmartGAPI](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6837-PHP-Display-site-statistics-from-Google-Analytics.html). Este componente tanto gera o HTML e JavaScript para inserir nas suas páginas, como também processa as requisições AJAX para encaminhar para a API do Google Analytics.